# Problem while compiling Latex project report

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I'm getting two problems while compiling my project report in latex (Texmaker, Miktex)

1. I'm getting blank pages after every page.
2. My Bibliography section is not showing (whose contents are in the file
   `mylit.bib`). It is supposed to show after Appendix section

please help me to overcome these problems.

Main tex file code

```
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright]{report}
\documentclass[twoside]{iitbreport}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\graphicspath{{expt/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

%%% Macro definitions for Commonly used symbols
\newcommand{\Rey}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{Re}}}
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\ensuremath{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tenpow}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}}

% Referencing macros
\newcommand{\Eqref}[1]{Equation~\eqref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Tabref}[1]{Table~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\Appref}[1]{Appendix~\ref{#1}}


\begin{document}

%%********************************Frontmatter***********************
% In frontmatter everything comes with roman numbering  
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%*******************************************************************
%                         Title Page                            
%*******************************************************************
\title{Project Title}
\author{William Blake}

%% Print the date. Today's date comes by default, change it here to 
%% other date format, if required:

\date{\today}
%\date{10 Mar 2016}

%% The type of the report can be set here

\reporttype{A Project Report}

%% Name of the degree
\degree{Master of Science}

%% Department/Centre Name
\dept{Department of Chemical Engineering}

%% Supervisor and cosupervisor/excosupervisor name can be put here
\supervisor{Prof. Satya Narayan}

%% Roll number
\rollnum{Roll No. : 4334334}

\maketitle                  

%*******************************************************************
%                        Certificate Page                         
%*******************************************************************
%\makecertificate[change title name]{report type} 
%\makecertificate{thesis}
%\makecertificate{dissertation}
\makecertificate{project report}

%\addintoc{Certificate}

%*******************************************************************
%                         Approval Sheet                         
%*******************************************************************
%\makeapproval{thesis}
%\makeapproval{dissertation}

%*******************************************************************
%                          Declaration                           
%*******************************************************************
\begin{Declaration}
\noindent
I declare that this written submission represents my ideas in my own words and where others' ideas or words have been included, I have adequately cited and referenced the original sources. I declare that I have properly and accurately acknowledged all sources used in the production of this report. I also declare that I have adhered to all principles of academic honesty and integrity and have not misrepresented or fabricated or falsified any idea/data/fact/source in my submission. I understand that any violation of the above will be a cause for disciplinary action by the Institute and can also evoke penal action from the sources which have thus not been properly cited or from whom proper permission has not been taken when needed.

%
%
%
%
%
%
%

\DecSign[\today]

%
\end{Declaration}

%*******************************************************************
%                        Acknowledgements                    
%******************************************************************* 
%%%
\acknowledgments

This section is for the acknowledgments. Please keep this brief and resist the temptation of writing flowery prose! Do include all those who helped you, e.g. other faculty/staff you consulted, colleagues who assisted etc.






\signature{\today}
%\signature[Indian Institute of Technology Bombay]{\today}

%******************************************************************
%                          Abstract                             
%******************************************************************  
\begin{Abstract}
This document contains essential templates required to write technical
reports using \LaTeX.  Particularly it shows how to create an
equation, figure, table, symbols list, and bibliographic citation in a \LaTeX\
document.
%
%
%
%
%
\end{Abstract}

%******************************************************************
%                         Contents list                         
%******************************************************************
%\figurespagefalse
%\tablespagefalse
\makecontents % Creats toc, lof, and lot

%******************************************************************
%                        Notations                              
%******************************************************************
\notations[4cm]{List of Symbols}      

%%********************************Mainmatter***********************
% In mainmatter everything comes with arabic numbering  
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%****************************************************************
%                         Appendices                           
%****************************************************************
%% Additional, supporting material, such as codes, derivations, etc., can be placed in the appendix
\appendix
\chapter{Supporting Material}

%******************************************************************
%                         Bibliography or References          
%******************************************************************  
\bibliography{mylit}  % @@@@@@@@@@@@@@ Not Showing @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

\end{document}
```

Class file code

```
%********************* New class: iitbreport.cls**********************
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{iitbreport} [23/10/2015 IIT Bombay Report class v 1.2]
\typeout{Document Class 'iitbreport' v1.2beta <10 Feb 16>}

%******************************************************************** 
% We need command to switch between dissertation, annual progress 
% seminar report, and thesis, and between different types of  
% reports. 
%*******************************************************************
\newif\if@draft
\newif\if@seminar
\newif\if@degree

\DeclareOption{twoside}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{twoside}{report}
}

\DeclareOption{draft}{%
  \@drafttrue
  \PassOptionsToClass{draft}{report}
}


\DeclareOption{seminar}{%
  \@seminartrue
}


%*****************************************************************
% Process given options
% Defaults
%****************************************************************** 
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{report}}  

\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper,openright]{report}


%***************Some important packages ****************************
% ams: for maths
% hyperref: for linking various labels
% graphicx: to add graphics
% fontenc, txfonts: important for character encoding, common font
% fancyhdr: fancy headr and footer
% nomencl: list of symbols
% natbib: to create references
%********************************************************************
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\RequirePackage[bookmarks,%
            breaklinks,%
            backref=false,%
            pdfhighlight=/I,%
            pdffitwindow=true,%
            pdfstartview=Fit,%
            pdfcenterwindow=true,%
            linkbordercolor={1 0 1},%
            pdfusetitle]
            {hyperref}

\RequirePackage[varg]{txfonts}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\putiitblogo}{\includegraphics[width=10em]{iitb-black}}


%******************page margins ******************************
%% Adjusted to a4 paper (29.7 x 21 cm)
\marginparwidth=0pt
\marginparsep=0pt
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\voffset{-1in}

\setlength{\topmargin}{14mm}
\setlength{\textheight}{245mm}
%\setlength\footskip{13mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{6mm}
% bottom margin is 22mm, total height: 14+245+10+6+22=29.7 mm

\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\if@twoside
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{34mm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{26mm}
\else
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{30mm}  
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{30mm} 
\fi
% total width for two side: 160+30+20=210 mm

%******************notations with nomecl***************************
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage[intoc,refpage]{nomencl}\makenomenclature
\renewcommand*{\pagedeclaration}[1]{~\dotfill\hyperpage{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\@mkboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}

\renewcommand*{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\large \textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%               
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{\vskip5mm\item[\large\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%          
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\vskip5mm\item[\large\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{\vskip5mm\item[\large\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%         
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{\vskip5mm\item[\large\textbf{Acronyms}]}{% 
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{\vskip5mm\item[\large\textbf{\@OtherSym}]}{%           
  }}}}}}
}

\newcommand*{\nmR}[3][]{\nomenclature[A#1]{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\nmG}[3][]{\nomenclature[B#1]{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\nmS}[3][]{\nomenclature[C#1]{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\nms}[3][]{\nomenclature[D#1]{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\nmA}[3][]{\nomenclature[E#1]{#2}{#3}}

\def\OtherSym#1{\gdef\@OtherSym{#1}}
\def\@OtherSym{Other Symbols}
\newcommand*{\nmX}[3][]{\nomenclature[X#1]{#2}{#3}}

\newcommand*{\nm}[2]{\nomenclature{#1}{#2}} % for simple list

\newcommand*{\notations}[2][4cm]{%
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand*{\nomname}{#2}%       
    \printnomenclature[#1]
    }

%\newcommand*{\Unit}[1]{%
%   \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{%
%       \hspace*{\hfill}[#1]\nolinebreak\hspace*{4cm}\mbox{}}%

%\newcommand*{\nomheaders}{%
%   \item[\bfseries Symbol]%
%   \textbf{Description}\hfill\textbf{Page}\ignorespaces
%   }           


%******************reference and citation styles********************  
%% In a thesis/report it the bibliography is called ``References'' 
%% The style file for References (Rev. Mod. Phys long
%% apsrmp4-1long.bst)
%%****************************************************************
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\let\mybibliography\bibliography
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{\makeheadtoc{References}\mybibliography{#1}}

\bibliographystyle{iitbauthyr}

%******************header-footer from fancyhdr.sty******************
\pagestyle{fancy}
% Heading marks
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{#1}{}
}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\thesection \hspace{1em} #1}
}

% Heading format
\fancyhead{} % clear old format
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\if@twoside
  \fancyhead[LO]{\em\nouppercase\rightmark}
  \fancyhead[RE]{\em\nouppercase\leftmark }
\else
  \fancyhead[L]{\em\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fi

\cfoot{}

%% redefine plain style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \cfoot{{\small\thepage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% this is to leave a page completely blank (without headers) when the
% document is used with a openright option (ref: fancyhdr.tex)

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{%
  \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi
}

%**********************Title page*************************************
% \author, \title, and \date are already defined in report
% Some new commands are defined here
% New commands: department, degree, supervisor, cosupervisors, rollnum
% Comments are welcomed
%**********************************************************************
\newcommand{\Usefont}[1]{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\monthyear}[1]{%
 \ClassWarning{iitbreport}{%
 \protect\monthyear\space command has been deprecated from Version 1.1 \space \MessageBreak
 use \protect\date\space instead.
 }
}

%% Indian date format DD Month YYYY
\renewcommand{\today}{%
\number\day\space%
\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May%
\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi%
\space\number\year
}
\gdef\@date{\today}

\nonstopmode   % Do not stop if the font is not available
\newcommand{\reporttype}[1]{\gdef\@reptype{#1}}
\gdef\@reptype{A Project Report}
\newcommand{\degree}[1]{\gdef\@degree{#1}\@degreetrue}
\gdef\@degree{}
\newcommand{\dept}[1]{\gdef\@dept{#1}}
\def\rollnum#1{\gdef\@rollnum{#1}}

\global\let\@supervisor\@empty
\def\supervisor#1{\gdef\@supervisor{#1}}

\global\let\@cosupervisor\@empty
\def\cosupervisor#1{\gdef\@cosupervisor{#1}}

\global\let\@excosupervisor\@empty
\def\excosupervisor#1{\gdef\@excosupervisor{#1}}

\global\let\@dept\@empty
\def\dept#1{\gdef\@dept{#1}}

\gdef\@rollnum{}

\newcommand{\@declaration}{%
    {\large \em \Usefont{pzc} 
      \@reptype \par
      %\vspace{\stretch{0.3}}       
      \if@degree{
        Submitted in partial fulfillment of  \\ [.25\baselineskip] 
        the requirements for the degree of \par
        {\Usefont{ppl}   \bfseries  \@degree }
      }
       \\ [.25\baselineskip]      
      \fi
       by} \par
        \vspace{\stretch{0.3}}
      } 


\if@seminar % 
  \ClassWarning{iitbreport}{%
  \MessageBreak
  seminar option deprecated.\MessageBreak
  Use \protect\reporttype\space instead.
  \MessageBreak
  }
\fi

%\newcommand{\makecoverpage}{%
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{titlepage}
  {%
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}\normalsize
%  \pdfbookmark[0]{Title}{Title}  
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  {\begin{center}
   {\Usefont{ptm}
      {\Usefont{phv} \LARGE \bfseries \@title \par}
      \vspace{\stretch{0.3}}
       \@declaration
        \vspace{.25\baselineskip} 
      {\large \bfseries \@author \par}
      \vspace{.25\baselineskip}  
      {\large (\@rollnum)}\vspace{\stretch{0.3}}           


         \ifx\@supervisor\@empty
         \ifx\@excosupervisor\@empty
           \ifx\@cosupervisor\@empty  
           \par        
          \fi \fi

          \else  
          \ifx\@excosupervisor\@empty
             \ifx\@cosupervisor\@empty
        {\large Supervisor:\par} \vspace{.25\baselineskip}  
        {\large \bfseries \@supervisor \par}       

         \else                    
               {\large Supervisors:\par} \vspace{.25\baselineskip}  
              {\large \bfseries \@supervisor \par} \vspace{.25\baselineskip}    
              and \par \vspace{.25\baselineskip}      
              {\large\bfseries\@cosupervisor \par}
              \fi      

       \else              
       {\large Supervisors:\par} \vspace{.25\baselineskip}  
              {\large \bfseries \@supervisor \par}  \vspace{.25\baselineskip}      
              {\large\bfseries\@cosupervisor \par}
              \vspace{.25\baselineskip} 
               and \par \vspace{.25\baselineskip}  
              {\large\bfseries\@excosupervisor \par}           

        \fi \fi       

      \vspace{\stretch{0.3}}
      \if@draft
      \else\putiitblogo
       \fi\par      

      {\Usefont{ptm}
       \ifx\@dept\@empty
       \vspace{\stretch{0.25}}
      {\large XYZ University \\[0.25\baselineskip]
        Mumbai 400076  (India)}        
        \else
      \vspace{\stretch{0.25}}
              {\large \@dept  \\[0.25\baselineskip]
                XYZ University \\[0.25\baselineskip]
                Delhi 653478  (India) }
        \fi  

        \vspace{.25\baselineskip}
        {\Large \@date \par}
        }
       } 
    \end{center}
   }
    }
    \end{titlepage}
} % coverpage


%**************************Certificate page*************************
\newcommand*{\GuideSign}{%
    \begin{center}  
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.6\linewidth}c}
                      & \rule{4cm}{1pt}\\   
            Date: \@date    &  \@supervisor\\         
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{center}
}
\newcommand*{\makecertificate}[2][Acceptance Certificate]{%
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection     
    \thispagestyle{empty}   
    \begin{center}  
        {\LARGE \textbf{#1} \par}\vspace{2\baselineskip} 
        {\large\textbf{\@dept}\par}\vspace{0.25\baselineskip} 
        {\large\textbf{XYZ University}}
    \end{center}
\vspace{1.5\baselineskip} 
The #2  entitled ``\@title'' submitted by \@author{} (\@rollnum{}) may be accepted for being evaluated.\par
\vspace{4\baselineskip} 
\noindent
\GuideSign  
    }


%**************************Copyright page******************************
\newcommand*{\mycopyright}{%
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection     
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}  
     \vspace*{19cm} 
    {\itshape\copyright\,\footnotesize \@date, by \@author\\    
        All rights reserved}    
}


%**************************Dedication ********************************
\newcommand*{\dedication}[1][]{%
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    {\centering\large\itshape\null\vfill #1\vfill\null}
}


%**************************Approval sheet*****************************
\newcommand*{\makeapproval}[2][Approval Sheet]{%
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection 
    \thispagestyle{empty}
        \begin{center}
            {\LARGE \bfseries #1}\\[2\baselineskip]         
        \end{center}
This #2 entitled ``\@title'' by \@author\ is approved for the degree of \@degree.
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{2\baselineskip}  
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
            \begin{tabular}{p{0.45\linewidth}c}
                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt}\\
                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt} \\
                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt} \\[-8mm] 
                & {Examiners} \\ [7mm]              

                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt} \\
                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt} \\
                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt} \\ [-8mm]               
                & Supervisor (s) \\ [7mm] 

                & \rule{6.5cm}{1pt}\\ [-8mm]                
                & Chairman \\ [7mm]                 

                Date: \rule{3cm}{1pt} & \\
                Place: \rule{3cm}{1pt} &\\          
            \end{tabular}   
        \end{center}\cleardoublepage    
}     


%**************************Declaration********************************
\newcommand*{\DecSign}[1][\today]{% 
    \vspace{3cm}  
    \begin{center}  
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.6\linewidth}c}
                      & \rule{4cm}{1pt}\\   
                      &  \@author\\
       Date: #1       & (\@rollnum) \\
        \end{tabular}   
    \end{center}
}
\newenvironment{Declaration}[1][Declaration]{%
    \cleardoublepage\phantomsection     
        \chapter*{#1}
    }{}


%*************************Abstract*************************************
\newenvironment{Abstract}[1][Abstract]{%    
\makeheadtoc{#1}\chapter*{#1}}{%    
}
%\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\Large Abstract}

%*************************Makecontents*********************************
% Change contents name
% Adding lof and lot into toc
% Adding toc into pdf bookmark
%**********************************************************************
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\newif\iffigurespage
\newif\iftablespage 
\figurespagetrue % default 
\tablespagetrue  % default
\def\makecontents{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{\contentsname}   
    \tableofcontents 
    \@mkboth{\contentsname}{\contentsname}  

    \iffigurespage \makeheadtoc{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
    \fi 

    \iftablespage \makeheadtoc{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
    \fi
    \cleardoublepage     
}

\newcommand*{\addintoc}[2][chapter]{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{#2}\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    }
\newcommand{\makeheadtoc}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
    \markboth{#1}{#1}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
}

%% The macros for the  Acknowledgements, List of publications  
\newcommand*{\acknowledgments}[1][Acknowledgements]{%   
    \makeheadtoc{#1}
    \chapter*{#1}
}

\newcommand*{\listofpublications}[1][List of Publications]{%    
    \makeheadtoc{#1}    
    \chapter*{#1}
}

% Adding signature
\newcommand*{\signature}[2][XYZ University]{%
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \emph{\bfseries \@author}\\
        #1 \\ #2
    \end{flushright}
}

%**************************Chapter style*****************************
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{50\p@}%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
    }}

    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        \vspace*{50\p@}%
        {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
            \normalfont
            \interlinepenalty\@M
            \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
            \vskip 40\p@
        }}


%**********************Section/subsection styles********************
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{-.7\baselineskip\@plus-\baselineskip}{.5\baselineskip}%
  {\Large\normalfont\bfseries\hsize1\textwidth \raggedright}}

\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\baselineskip\@plus.7\baselineskip}{0.5\baselineskip}%
  {\large\normalfont\bfseries\raggedright}}
%\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
%  \z@\z@{0.5\baselineskip}%
%  {\normalfont\itshape\raggedright}}

\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                         {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                         {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                         {\normalfont\itshape\raggedright}}


%********************* Paragraph, line spacing********************
% Indentation 5 characters approx
% Paragraph spacing
% Line spacing (onehalfspacing is equal to baselinestretch 1.33)
%*****************************************************************
\parindent 5ex
%\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.33}


%**************************Widow and orphan************************
% Widow and orphan settings
% Requirements for the thesis format
% Orphan (removes single line at bottom of page)
% Widow (removes single line at top of page)
%*****************************************************************
\clubpenalty=10000  
\widowpenalty=10000  

%**************************Other settings************************
\sloppy
\raggedbottom



\endinput

%======================================================================
% END FILE: `iitbreport.cls'
%======================================================================
```

Here is the complete [Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cv62glq3e7lt9mh/p_report.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to illustrate your problem. External links are not very useful because they may not be around in a few years time - and people are more likely to answer your question if they can see the code straightaway. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. Cutting your code down to a MWE may well reveal what your problem actually is.

Comment: @Andrew the code is too long

Comment: That's part of my point: you need to cut it down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) if  you want people to look at it.

Comment: What happened to the first fourty lines of the class file? The lines where it is told what you are allowed to do and what you are not allowed to do. I hereby complain. https://github.com/psunthar/iitbreport/blob/master/iitbreport.cls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I tried your style file and is not true that blank pages appear after every page. The style does insert a blank page if a chapter (or appendix, list of ..., basically everything in your example) does not start with a page on the right side. That is intended and you've most likely seen that in books. If you add a `\chapter{test}` with a lot of text, you'll see that there are no blank pages during that text.
2. You do not cite anything, so naturally the bibliography is empty. I don't have `iitbauthyr.bst` (the natbib style file of your class), but I replaced it with one of mine, citet something (`\citet{BIBKEY}`) and the "References" chapter appeared.